# Wordpress: Adding a widget to the main body (not the sidebar), widget not showing up

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, widget

I followed the instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes) for how to add a widget to a template. I added this code to functions.php:

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Carousel',
        'id'            => 'carousel_widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

and I added this to my custom template:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'carousel_widget' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="carousel-widget" class="carousel widget-area">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'carousel_widget' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It worked, but my new widget showed up as a sidebar, and I want it to be in the main body of the page. Obviously this is because of the `dynamic_sidebar` function, but the documentation is not very helpful on how to place a widget on the page NOT as a sidebar.

I tried replaced the php with this:

```
<div id="carousel-widget" class="carousel widget-area">
    <?php the_widget( 'carousel_widget' ); ?>
</div>
```

But now it doesn't show up at all.

How do I place this widget on my page without it showing up as an absolutely positioned sidebar?